# Probability - die - The number of throws until a $5$ and a $6$ have been obtained.

Tags: probability

An unbiased die is thrown repeatedly until a 5 and a 6 have been obtained. the random variable M denotes the number of throws required. For example, for the sequence of results 6,3,2,3,6,6,5, the value of M is 7. Calculate P(M=r).

Comment: If $r>33$ your expression is negative.

Comment: When I read the title, I amplified it to "Probability - die die die!"

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_1$ be the number of throws until either a $5$ or a $6$ appears,

and let $X_2$ be the number of additional throws until the other one appears.

Then $X = X_1 + X_2$ is the total number of throws required,

where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent geometric random variables

with parameters $p_1 = 1/3$ and $p_2 = 1/6$, respectively.

Comment: Is the answer 〖(2/3)〗^(X_1-1)(1/3) 〖(5/6)〗^( X_2-1) (1/6) ?

Comment: @All Its the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Our required probability is $\Pr(M\gt r-1)-\Pr(M\gt r)$.

We find $\Pr(M\gt n)$. We have $M\gt n$ if in the first $n$ tosses, $5$ is missing, or $6$ is missing, or both are missing. The probability $5$ is missing is $(5/6)^n$. The probability $6$ is missing is the same. The probability  both are missing is $(4/6)^n$. Thus $\Pr(M\gt n)=(5/6)^n+(5/6)^n-(4/6)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the $r$-th one is $6$. Then in the previous $r-1$ throw, you must have at least one $5$. That means at the same time you cannot have $6$. So you can have one $5$ and $(r-2)$ $1-4$, or two $5$ and $(r-3)$ $1-4$, ... etc.

So the probability is

$$P=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^{r-1}C^{r-1}_i \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^i\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{r-2-i}$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\bigg[\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{3}\right)^{r-1}-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{r-1}\bigg]$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\frac{5^{r-1}-4^{r-1}}{6^{r-1}}$$

Finally, switching the role of $5$ and $6$ means doubling the probability, so

$$P=\frac{1}{3}\frac{5^{r-1}-4^{r-1}}{6^{r-1}}$$